# My GitHub account is set up with 2 factor authentication, yet username/password aren't requested when cloning a repository

Tags: git, github, two-factor-authentication

My GitHub account is set up with 2 factor authentication

[image: 2 factor authentication enabled]

No personal access tokens are listed

[image: Empty list of personal access tokens]

And yet I am able to clone a repository without being asked for a username or password.

[image]

How come?

Comment: Is your repository public? Do you have an SSH key set up for github?

Comment: @Leon: 1. I don't pay GitHub for hosting. This means that my repository is public, right?, 2. Yes, I have an SSH key set up for github, but in the example above I connected via https. Moreover, as far as I know there's no ssh-agent running in the background (but I may be wrong; I don't know how to check this.)

Comment: Public repositories don't require authentication for cloning over https

Comment: @Leon: I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In github all your projects are public unless you pay for private repo.
Anyone with github account can clone your projects.

The 2 way authentication is for protecting your account not your projects since they are all public.

If you want private repositories use [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/product). You can have private repositories there.

---

https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/

> After 2FA is enabled, GitHub generates an authentication code **any time someone attempts to sign into your GitHub account**.
>
> The only way someone can sign into your account is if they know both your password and have access to the authentication code on your phone.